# Handling inbound links in AngularJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have a single-page application and I have all my internal links working with `ng-click`, which dynamically loads data into `ng-view`. I'm trying to figure out how to handle inbound links from outside the app, for example a link to `'ROOT_PATH.com/#/posts/250'`.

My `$routeProvider` catches the route and correctly loads the specific post data. From that point, when I click on the posts index `ng-click` link, it correctly loads and shows the posts index, but the route is still `'ROOT_PATH.com/#/posts/250'`.

I'd like the app to always show the root path. Or at least always show the root path when posts index is displayed.

```
$routeProvider.when('/posts/:postId', { templateUrl: '../assets/mainIndex.html', controller: 'PostCtrl' } )

# Default
$routeProvider.otherwise({ templateUrl: '../assets/mainIndex.html', controller: 'IndexCtrl' } )
```